# How can I know the URI of the dead letter queue?

Tags: wcf, msmq

When using MSMQ and WCF, **please describe the algorithm/rules which decide the URI of the dead letter queue?**

For example: `net.msmq://localhost/private/MyQueue;DeadLetter` or `net.msmq://localhost/system$;DeadLetter` or something else?

I ask because I found a Transcender question where I disagree about the answer, but I haven't been able to find a clear definition which describes exactly the rules.  I have checked MSDN and both fish books.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [MSDN docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms789035.aspx), this is your answer:

> Reading Messages from the Dead-Letter Queue
>
> An application that reads messages out of a dead-letter queue is
>   similar to a WCF service that reads from an application queue, except
>   for the following minor differences:
>
> To read messages from a system transactional dead-letter queue, the Uniform Resource Identifier (URI) must be of the form:
>     **`net.msmq://localhost/system$;DeadXact`**
>
> To read messages from a system non-transactional dead-letter queue, the URI must be of the form:
>     **`net.msmq://localhost/system$;DeadLetter`**

You don't have a dead-letter queue *per URL / service* but one per system/machine.

Comment: I'm not sure that is the whole story.  I think private queues will not populate the public system$ queue.

Comment: @BuhBuh: can you show me any hint on the web that private queues would use something else?? I cannot find **anything**. Yes, you can define a custom dead letter queue - if you like - but I cannot find **any** hint anywhere that private queues would treat dead messages any different than public queues....

Comment: @BuhBuh: have you tried with that URL syntax and found that it doesn't work??

Comment: I have not tried it.  The only place I can find is my Transcender question, which suggests that private queues populate a dead letter queue with the same name but postfixed ";DeadLetter". I think perhaps they have it wrong. I would like to share a screen shot but I expect I will get in trouble. I will log a question with Transcender and see what they have to say.  Thanks for your time Marc.

Comment: Ok, I have sent them a message and will let you know their response. One thing that makes me think they may be right is that a private queue should be private one machine. The system$ queues are public on the network. It doesn't sound secure for messages to go from private to public. I'm just not sure.

Comment: Private and public has zero to do with security. My telephone number can be private that doesn't stop anyone ringing it. It just means it hasn't been published to a directory.

Comment: "The system$ queues are public on the network." System$ queues are not public as they are not published to Active Directory.

Comment: @marc_s: Transcender have comfirmed that you are correct.  They say they will fix their answer.  Thanks for your help.